# Keep just index and not name in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this

```
variable    id Max
0   8004    5
1   8005    10
2   8006    9
3   8034    14
4   8046    3
```

if I check the df.columns I get

```
Index(['id', 'Max'], dtype='object', name='variable')
```

But I dont care the variable, I want to keep the information in the index but that appears as columns and delete the variable. I don't know if it is important, but I get the dataframe by pivoting another table.

Comment: Use `del df.index.name`

Comment: It doesn't work. Nothing change

Comment: What does `print(df.index.name)` give you?

Comment: That gives me 'None'

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with `None` as the argument:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    variable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    id = [8004, 8005, 8006, 8034, 8046],
    Max = [5, 10, 9, 14, 3],
)).set_index('variable')

df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

[Python Tutor link to example](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20variable%20%3D%20%5B0,%201,%202,%203,%204%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20id%20%3D%20%5B8004,%208005,%208006,%208034,%208046%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20Max%20%3D%20%5B5,%2010,%209,%2014,%203%5D,%0A%29%29.set_index%28'variable'%29%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20df.rename_axis%28None%29%0A&cumulative=true&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)